# Ios cross compilation frameworks: do they violate the Ios SDK license?

Tags: ios, adobe, delphi-xe, marmalade

Some cross compilation frameworks like Adobe Air, Marmalade sdk, Trigger.io and Embarcadero  allow one to build test and debug applications from a windows machine. Do they violate the iOS SDK license agreement? This agrement forbids to distribute derivative work of the SDK which is the certainly the case with the above mentioned products. Is it safe to use this products for development or is there a concrete danger that Apple will retire any app developed with these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I can comment on the trigger.io side of things..

My understanding of things is that the forge build process is acting much like testflightapp, just without the download / install process.

You never actually download / use the apple SDK so its hard to say if you are violating something that you are not using directly.

Forge, just like all build services, has a build server. The build server contains the IOS SDK for packaging. As long as your certs and provisioning files are correct it will package it up just fine. The forge process simply installs it after the fact, again similar to testflightapp.

As for apple knowing you tested in a specific manor.. I don't know how they could even know because the end package is just an ipa file, you still have to submit via a mac.

Comment: I guess it is similar although the specifics are very different. With marmalade you are building the code on your own machine, be it a Mac or a PC. On a PC, you won't be using the Apple SDK directly for any development, although you do need access to a Mac (usually very briefly) to upload to the iTunes store.

In the Marmalade approach, what you are doing is basically the same as using libraries generated by others, together with some tools. On a PC we have to replace some of the tools that would be there for free on a Mac, but we do so using open source code from Apple.